# Left and right constraint on UITableview cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I cannot add left and right constraints on the table as I don't want those constraints on all the cells. I want constraints on certain cells on left and right, however when I add the constraints programmatically, I don't see it working. I see bottom and top constraints working.

Using auto-layout, my table view's left and right constraint is equal to main view's left and right, cell's content view is aligned to left and right of table view. Below is my code:

```
cell.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.topAnchor, constant: 6.0).isActive = true
cell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 6.0).isActive = true

cell.contentView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.leftAnchor, constant: 9.0).isActive = true
cell.contentView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.rightAnchor, constant: 9.0).isActive = true
cell.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 9.0).isActive = true
cell.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.contentView.rightAnchor, constant: 9.0).isActive = true
```

Here is how it looks with these constraints:

[image]

How do I add left and right constraints or space between the cell and the device edge on left and right side of the cell?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I add left and right constraints or space between the cell and the device edge on left and right side of the cell?

You don't. The "device edge" is irrelevant and outside your purview.

The cell is part of the table view and is placed where it is placed by the table view. It isn't up to you. Nor is the position of the content view up to you.

Positioning the contents of the content view within the content view, however, is just fine. Indeed, you have configurable margins for this very purpose.